# That time of year again -- hats!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hats

For the last couple years Stack Exchange has done something fun and lighthearted as the year ends, **Winter Bash**.  Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges, but temporary). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats in a leaderboard, and you can track your own progress across all sites where you participate.

This year the event will run from December 15 to January 4.  Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available.  And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.

So, shall we opt in again this year?  **Please upvote the answer you favor but don't downvote**, so we can get a clear sense of how people feel.

Comment: Is there some other goal than "have some fun in a  lighthearted way"? Has anyone conducted a poll after the fact to try and see if the community found it accomplished the desired goal?

Comment: Yay! Yay! Yay! Yay! I loved the hats. Far too much. I can't explain it...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere it doesn't look like anybody's conducted a poll *here*, but if you go over to Meta.SE and look through the "winterbash" tags (there's one for each year), you'll see lots of discussion there.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - thanks!

Comment: Sounds awesome!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes!  Hats are fun.  Or if you don't think they're fun, at least they're harmless -- you can ignore them if you don't want to play.

Comment: The voting seems pretty clear.  I signed us up.

Comment: LESS TALKING MORE HATS-ING

Answer (score 15):

How can I not want hats with this avatar?

Answer (score 8):

*Just for an additional choice that folks can vote on ...*

Meh. Hats or no hats - it doesn't matter to me either way.

Answer (score 4):

No!  We don't want hats.  Coworkers might see.

Comment: And feel mighty envious...