# What should we do with the Ontario tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Just recently the [ontario](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ontario) was created, and it's currently only used on [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/112692/73791) question.

*What should we do with that tag?* Seems that this may lead to confusion, as there are many places called Ontario, not just the one in Canada.

Should we be sticking to country tags instead?

Comment: Get rid of it, we don't need it

Comment: [Fly it proudly?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Ontario#/media/File:Flag_of_Ontario.svg)

Comment: Seems that the tag no longer exists (or at least has 0 questions tagged now)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kill it with fire.

Stick with the country specific tags.  There might be other jurisdictional areas of countries that might need to be tagged differently, but Ontario is not one of them.

Comment: Canadian law is not that different that we need tags for every province. Yes there are things that different on a provincial base, but not so drastically that an answer would be blatantly incorrect. I agree burninate this tag.

Answer (score 10):

We can only specify 5 tags for a question, so let us not use up 2 tags for location. Specify the country in the tag, and put city/state details in the post.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're asking two questions at once:

> Do we need to break countries down into sub-tags for other areas of jurisdiction?

I don't have answer for that, and it seems like the community doesn't, either. There are tags for "California" and "Florida" but not "New York."

Second, assuming we justify that level of detail,

> Is "Ontario" the right way to tag Ontario, Canada?

I think we have an answer to this when you said,

> there are many places called Ontario, not just the one in Canada

If we decide to keep the tag, it should probably be edited into Ontario-Canada or something similar.

Comment: [Our tags are kind of a mess](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5006/3192) though. The privilege to create tags comes far too early on the ladder making it way too easy to create tags. The presence or absence of a specific tag doesn't necessarily say anything about the "validity" of that tag. See also a [mod election question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5189/3192) that wasn't shortlisted. I plan to work on this some time after this mod election is over.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that was indirectly my point, our tags are a mess! It's hard to answer, "do we need this tag?" in light of that mess. I agree, it's too easy to create tags.

Comment: California and Florida are different jurisdictions and have significantly different state laws, so it makes sense to have those tags. Is this also the case for Ontario? For many countries the laws are *not* different per province/region, but the same throughout the country.