# Announcement: Some cleaning and changes done to our Meta Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I took some time to do some cleaning and organizing of our tags here on Meta TWP.

What inspired me to do so is that [our tags are kind of a mess](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5006/73791) right now, and also because I noticed we have requests to burninate but had no tag for such requests. I also noticed some inconsistencies on the previous tags used to indicate a synonym or re-tag request. Also, none of them had excerpt or wiki. Thus, here are the things I did:

- **Created the [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) tag, along with its excerpt and Guidance Wiki**. Then, proceeded to include such tag on all burninate request posts I could find.
- **Created the [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) tag, along with its excerpt.** Previously, we were using the [merge](/questions/tagged/merge) tag on retag request posts, or even the [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) tag. However this was confusing as the merge tag was also used in question merge requests, and retagging reads more like the process itself.

  Also, this new wording is consistent to the one used in other sites. Thus, I also proceeded to retag/merge the [merge](/questions/tagged/merge) for the new [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) on all posts I could find that applied (talk about inception).
- **Created the [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) tag, along with its excerpt.** Previously we used the [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) tag for such, but it lacked description and also a more adequate name (as "tag synonyms" reads more about the synonyms *per se*, not about a request to create one).

  Besides being more adequate, this wording is also consistent to the one used on other sites on the network. I also proceeded to include and re-tag all posts that applied and that I could find.

I am writing this post to let you all know about these changes I did, so we can all *be aware of the new, proper tags, and use them when they correspond*. Hopefully this will bring more structure and consistency to our tags.

Also, I would like to hear any **feedback and suggestions you may have that could help further organize and improve our tags**, as well as any issues you may see with this (although I think organizing tags can hardly have drawbacks).

Comment: Yep, all looks good here.  I'm not so sure about the retag-request tag as people normally just edit the question to appropriately tag it...

Comment: Thanks for putting in the effort here, looks good to me as well.

Comment: Lost me just after ... 'Today...'... but seems like you went to a bit of effort so... great stuff!!

Comment: We appreciate the work Dark, thanks for doing this!

Comment: @Snow true, but in more complex cases, like where consensus is needed or where the number of posts in need of retagging is big, the tag will be useful.